# Snaplogic REST POST Snap: Failing with SSL error

Tags: snaplogic

I am trying to post a simple json to our backend api through REST POST snap. Everything was working. And then we changed the url to a new url and I updated the url in the snap.
But now request is simply not reaching our new api server.

In fact, the snaplogic pipeline also completes successfully, with all snaps turning green. Only when I click on the properties of pipeline, I get to know that REST POST snap has failed, with attached screenshot error.

Please note that we are able to reach the new api server via postman or any other rest client. Nothing has changed at all except for the url.

[image]

Can you please help me understand, what exactly is going wrong and where? How to debug this?

Comment: Can you please share the whole error? And, also the snap settings?

Comment: Hi @Bilesh, I was able to find out the cause - basically the pod in which snaplogic instance is running is not able to reach the api url or at least not all the times because of zscaler firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone's reference, I was able to find out the root cause.
Reason was that the **api url was not accessible to snaplogic pod** running in our enterprise because of Zscaler firewall.

The confusing part here was the error message returned which says "SSL issue, connection was reset". So if you see issue saying "Connection was reset", assume that snaplogic is unable to access the url as the first problem. Only after making sure, it is not the case, go and look for what exactly the error says.